# Unexpected token ', ' in 4th line of code in R

Tags: r, dplyr, unexpected-token

I am getting started with 'R', I am following some lecture and i typed the exact same code as in lecture, But I am getting a cross flag which says that Unexpected token ' , ' in my fourth line of the code

```
data(`ToothGrowth`)
View(ToothGrowth)
install.packages(`dplyr`)
filtered_tg <- (ToothGrowth,dose==0.5)
```

Comment: You seem to have forgotten the verb „filter“ in your last line of code.

Answer (score 2):

dont fortget to write the function name before.

```
filtered_tg <- filter(ToothGrowth, dose==0.5)
```

Comment: And a `library(dplyr)`  somewhere before the filter call and after the dplyr installation